# Is there a way to get the pathname of Chrome's default download folder using the Chrome Extensions API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The closest thing I've seen is `chrome.downloads.showDefaultFolder()`, but that opens up a file dialog. Is there a way to get the folder pathname as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no convenient way to get the "physical" location of the downloads directory through the Chrome extension API.

In theory, you could enable access to local URLs (at `chrome://extensions/`), download a file, then search through the directories on the disk via XHR and/or content scripts for the target directory. This is not practical though. First because it is extremely inefficient, and secondly because normal users will not allow your extension to access their disk.

Comment: Yeah, I figured the capability might not exist in the API. The workaround does seem too hackish to use, but it's good to know it exists. For stackoverflow questions like this, should I accept the "no" answer, or leave it open?

Comment: @iqnivek An authorative no is also an (acceptable) answer, until someone else passes by and says "XXX is now possible, here's how: ...". In that case you can simply accept the new answer.